# Server not returning the last response message to client

Tags: c, sockets

I made a client/server program where for every command from client server returns "Hello, From server" and for exit it should return "Exiting the server" but it returns "Hello, From server" and exits

I tried by putting a string before and break statement and also put a string after while loop both are printed while ending from the server is not printing to the client

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void)
{
    int client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //creating client socket

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;  //creating structure for server address
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if(connect(client_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address,sizeof(server_address))<0)  //establishing connection between client and server
    {
        printf("Something went wrong while connecting to server!\n");
        close(client_socket);
        return -3;
    }

    char server_response[256];  //creating buffer for receiving data from server
    char client_request[256];   // creating buffer for sending request from the client
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter command: ");
        scanf("%s",client_request);
        send(client_socket,&client_request,sizeof(char)*strlen(client_request),0); // sending command from the client
        memset(server_response,0,sizeof(server_response)); // cleaning the buffer
        recv(client_socket,&server_response,sizeof(server_response),0); //data receiving from the server
        printf("%s\n",server_response); //printing data to console
        if(strcmp(client_request,"exit")==0)break; // termnating condition for the client
    }
    close(client_socket);   //closing the socket
    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

void print_client(struct sockaddr_in client_address)
{
    unsigned long address = ntohl(client_address.sin_addr.s_addr);
    unsigned int a = (address & (0xff));
    unsigned int b = (address & (0xff <<  8)) >>  8;
    unsigned int c = (address & (0xff << 16)) >> 16;
    unsigned int d = (address & (0xff << 24)) >> 24;
    printf("Cient address: %u.%u.%u.%u ",d,c,b,a);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    char server_msg[256] = "Hello, From server";    // server response message
    char end_msg[256] = "Exiting the server";// server ending message
    char client_request[256];
    int client_request_len;
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // creating tcp/ip socket for server

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;  // creating server address
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;    
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if(bind(server_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) //binding socket to server address
    {
        printf("Could not bind address try later!\n");
    }
    listen(server_socket, 5); //making connection limited to 5 clients
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    unsigned int client_address_len;
    int client_socket = accept(server_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address,&client_address_len);   //accepting the client request
    print_client(client_address);
    printf(" and port: %u connected\n",client_address.sin_port);
    send(client_socket,server_msg,sizeof(server_msg),0);
    while(1)
    {
        memset(client_request,0,sizeof(client_request)); // cleaning the buffer
        recv(client_socket,&client_request,sizeof(client_request),0); // receiving request from client
        printf("Message from client: %s\n",client_request);
        if(strcmp(client_request,"exit")==0)
        {
            printf("breaking condition\n");
            break; // terminating the connection
        }
        send(client_socket,server_msg,sizeof(server_msg),0);    // sending server_msg to client
    }
    printf("send this message\n");
    send(client_socket,end_msg,sizeof(end_msg),0);
    close(server_socket); // closing the server socket
    return 0;   
}
```

actual result 
"client" `Enter command: shubham
Hello, From server
Enter command: kumar
Hello, From server
Enter command: end
Hello, From server
Enter command: exit
Hello, From server`
expected result "client"

```
Hello, From server
Enter command: kumar
Hello, From server
Enter command: end
Hello, From server
Enter command: exit
Exiting the server
```

actual result "server"

```
Cient address: 127.0.0.1  and port: 20710 connected
Message from client: shubham
Message from client: kumar
Message from client: end
Message from client: exit
breaking condition
send this message
```

Comment: Where is end_msg and server_msg defined?

Comment: end_msg and server_msg are defined above as a string. Those are not so important code only problem lies in the given snippet

Comment: Seeing as the "actual result" from the server looks to be what you are expecting, the problem may be in the client-code that is reading the messages... it feels like it is not detecting that a different message is being returned. Can you show that code?

Comment: `while(1)
 {
  printf("Enter command: ");
  scanf("%s",client_request);
  send(client_socket,&client_request,sizeof(char)*strlen(client_request),0); // sending command from the client
  memset(server_response,0,sizeof(server_response)); // cleaning the buffer
  recv(client_socket,&server_response,sizeof(server_response),0); //data receiving from the server
  printf("%s\n",server_response); //printing data to console
  if(strcmp(client_request,"exit")==0)break; // termnating condition for the client
 }
 close(client_socket); //closing the socket
 return 0;
`

Comment: Please edit your question. No code in the comment section.

Comment: Broken for the usual three reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you send `Hello, From server` already after accepting the client connection, so the order of events is something like this:

1. client: connect and wait for user input
2. server: accept the connection, send server message `S` (hello from server)
3. user: enter command `C` (whatever)
4. client: send `C`, read `S` from step 2, wait for user input
5. server: read `C`, send `S`
6. user: enter command `Exit`
7. client: send `Exit`, read `S` from step 5, exit
8. server: read `Exit`, send `E` (exit from server) but at this point the client is probably not connected any more.

If you remove that sending of the message after accepting the connection but before the `while` loop then it should work as expected.